# Instamojo Payment redirection

Tags: php, instamojo

I am creating a website in php. I need simple integration with Intsamojo payment gateway.
The php library i am using is https://github.com/Instamojo/instamojo-php/
I can generate a payment request like this example.

```
     try {
     $response = $api->paymentRequestCreate(array(
        "purpose" => "FIFA 16",
        "amount" => "3499",
        "send_email" => true,
        "email" => "foo@example.com",
        "redirect_url" => "http://www.example.com/handle_redirect.php"
        ));
      print_r($response);
}
    catch (Exception $e) {
    print('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

The `$response` variable have a unique payment response for the requested payment.

```
Array
(
    [id] => a78ab73df2bb4e78bc06a32a264ae59a
    [phone] => +919898989898
    [email] => ba@gmail.com
    [buyer_name] => mool
    [amount] => 105.75
    [purpose] => Jeans Mens #100
    [status] => Pending
    [send_sms] => 
    [send_email] => 1
    [sms_status] => 
    [email_status] => Pending
    [shorturl] => 
    [longurl] => https://test.instamojo.com/@instamojousername/a78ab73df2bb4e78bc06a32a264ae59a
    [redirect_url] => http://demo.test.com/instamojo/thankyou.php
    [webhook] => http://demo.test.com/instamojo/webhook.php
    [created_at] => 2016-08-19T14:44:10.679557Z
    [modified_at] => 2016-08-19T14:44:10.679582Z
    [allow_repeated_payments] => 
)
```

Now after this step i want redirect user to this link generated for payment.

```
https://test.instamojo.com/@instamojousername/a78ab73df2bb4e78bc06a32a264ae59a
```

How its possible after the first `paymentRequestCreate` call.
A simple header redirect is ok?  Which is secure method?

Answer (score 0):

in the "redirect_url" provide the link you want to redirect after the payment. for example "https://www.google.co.in/" like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it should be help to you

```
 try {
 $response = $api->paymentRequestCreate(array(
    "purpose" => "FIFA 16",
    "amount" => "3499",
    "send_email" => true,
    "email" => "foo@example.com",
    "redirect_url" => "http://www.example.com/handle_redirect.php"
    ));
    header('location:'.response['longurl']);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
print('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
            $response = $api->paymentRequestCreate(array(
                "purpose" => "Add Branch",
                "amount" => "2250",
                "send_email" => false,
                "email" => "",
                "redirect_url" => base_url()."coordinator/new_branch_response"
                ));

            header('Location: https://www.instamojo.com/your_unique_number/'.$response['id']);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Can you give more details why this is a solution for the given problem?

Comment: Because instamojo not give to direct access to user Instamojo works is send email to user with link. So, i can use this. I think this is better way.